# How to solve the function of javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pass"]) ) {
        unset($_SESSION["account"]);  // Logout current user
        if ( $_POST['pass'] == 'php123' ) {
            $_SESSION["account"] = $_POST["account"];
            $_SESSION["success"] = "Logged in.";
            header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
            return;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["error"] = "Incorrect password.";
            header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
            return;
        }
    }
?>

<?php // Do not put any HTML above this line
require_once "pdo.php";
if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sai Kumar</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<?php
    if ( isset($_SESSION["error"]) ) {
        echo('<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION["error"]."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
    }
?>
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<label for="nam">User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="nam"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="return doValidate();" value="Log In">
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
<script>
function doValidate() {
    console.log('Validating...');
    try {
          addr = document.getElementById('email').value;
          pw = document.getElementById('id_1723').value;
        console.log("Validating addr="+addr+" pw="+pw);
        if (addr == null || addr == "" || pw == null || pw == "") {
            alert("Both fields must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if ( addr.indexOf('@') == -1 ) {
            alert("Invalid email address");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

After clicking in login button its not working anymore. It just stays in that page. Cannot find where is the error.
The javascript should show an alert if i enter wrong password or email id without an @.
Help please.
added var infront of addr and pw but still same result.

Comment: What kind of exception were you hoping to catch here?

Comment: And what did you expect `document.getElementById('email')` to select?

Comment: <input type="text" name="email" id="nam"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
to capture the email entered by the user and the password.

Comment: And where exactly is that _ID_ `email` now …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no object with id email. Try

```
addr = document.getElementById('nam').value;
```

Comment: By the way you should see errors in your browsers console

Comment: i cant see any error in console.
its just showing validated... and nothing.

Comment: Change this `addr = document.getElementById('email').value;` to this `addr = document.getElementById('nam').value;`

Comment: Thank you. It solved. 
<label for="nam">User Name</label> i didnt see this line.

Comment: Wrong line. `<input type="text" name="email" id="nam">` your input id is #nam and you searching for #email